# MySQL query for how many customers live in each state

Tags: mysql

I have the table `'Customers'` with `(customerID, firstname, lastname, town, state)`

and I am trying to create an MySQL query for finding how many customers live in each state. Any help please?

Comment: SELECT chapter FROM manual WHERE title = 'relevant' ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),state FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY STATE
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me!